# Ionic publishing in Xcode 10

Tags: swift, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am a app developer using Ionic to create my first project.

Currently, I need to use:

> ionic cordova run ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"

and not:

> ionic cordova build ios

because basic ionic doesn't work with Xcode.

My Question is: Can I still publish my app to the app store even though I must use the special **"--buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"** to run my code?

Answer (score 2):

Update :

Cordova ios 5.0.0 has now been released and with it, this issue has been resolved. The below workaround can now be skipped.

Original Answer:

You can publish it to the App Store. However, it will be a debug build NOT a [production build](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/).

I would recommend downgrading xcode to version 9.x and then publishing the app until the next version of cordova ios is released.

Steps to downgrade xcode :

- Download an older version of xcode from the [Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Xcode)
- Unzip the content of the download
- Replace the xcode folder under Applications directory with the downloaded folder.

Cordova announcement: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407

Comment: Will people will the new iphones be able to use the app?

Answer (score 0):

Use

Xcode/File/Workplace Settings.../Legacy Build System.  Not New Build System (Default)